# Spring Boot AngularJs setting $log debug enabled from dynamic server value

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I am building an application with Spring Boot (jar) and AngularJS. I need the client debug log enabled property to be set based on the spring active profile.

There are multiple properties files on the server, and which one of them to use is determined by the spring active profile. A configuration file loads the correct properties with `@PropertySource(value = { "client.${spring.profiles.active:local}.properties" })`.

Next I am exposing these properties to an API call with a `@RestController`.

However, it seems that one cannot (without some serious hacking and potential race condition) perform an HTTP request within the AngularJS configuration. Neither can the $logProvider be manipulated outside the configuration.

I am at a loss, then, as to how I can, with best practices, get my log level property set.

When I was using non-Boot Spring, with JSTL, I could add a javascript variable to the global namespace in a JSP page, but Spring Boot (jar) does not support JSP.

I am looking for some insight into how I can allow my dynamic back end to set my AngularJS debug logging property.